# Laravel Eloquent - Find user in relational table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the user's reservation in between now and in next week. If a reservation exists the user gets removed from the possible selection.

I've made this `reservation()` function inside the User model:

```php
public function reservation(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Reservation::class, ['user_1_id', 'user_2_id', 'user_3_id', 'user_4_id'], 'id');
}
```

Finally where I return my view I'm trying to get the reservation like:

```php
$user = User::whereHas('reservation', function ($query) {
    $query->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()->addWeek()]);
})->first();
```

Then when a reservation exists I'd want to remove the user from the user collection and return the new collection of available users in the view. Now the issue is that I first get an error: `str_contains(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, array given` second how will I be able to remove the found users from the users collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the problem was:

I had to have an intermediate table I called it: "reservation_user" then the `reservation()` function needs to be replaced by:

```
    public function reservations(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Reservation::class, 'reservation_user', 'user_id', 'reservation_id');
    }
```

And then to get the users which don't have a reservation in between now and next week:

```
        $users = User::all();

        $usersWithReservations = User::has('reservations')
            ->whereHas('reservations', function($query) {
                $query->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()->addWeek()]);
            })
            ->get();

        if ($usersWithReservations->count() > 0) {
            $users = $users->reject(function($value) use($usersWithReservations) {
                return $usersWithReservations->contains('id', $value->id);
            });
        }
```

This function will return all users who don't have a reservation in between now and next week.